# And-or binary tree - splitting the tree according to requirements

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree, logical-operators

I'm recently trying to figure out an algorithm that would optimize a and-or binary tree, following some special rules, and I really can't figure it out. I'm thus hopeful that some of you may have had that kind of problem already.

There are some infos on the problems :

- The tree will be used to make a request on a server.
- There are two kinds of leaves : Data and price.
- Prices hold a currency information.
- In a same request, there can't be a OR between two Data.
- In a same request, there can't be a OR between two Prices of different currency.
- In a same request, there can't be a AND between two Prices of the same currency.

It may be blurry, so there's an example :

Example

[image]

Result

[image]

The grayed part is what the software would do with the result of the request.

I tried to code those by myself... but either it was continuing indefinitely, it wasn't doing what it was supposed to, it was crashing... or the three of them at the same time!

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Edit** : The requests must be as big as possible. I can't send each leaves individually, or the server will give an error back, because of too many results.

There is some code I did... be careful though, it's completly messy.

```
                    //Datas yet in the tree  //or/and to add at top  //The left part to add //The right part to add
    public Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>> DivideRequest(ExpressionAnalyzer.Element element)
    {
        switch (element.elementKind)
        {
            case "data":
                ExpressionAnalyzer.Data data = (element as ExpressionAnalyzer.Data);
                data.elementValide = true;
                return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                      (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(new List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data> { data }, ""), 
                       new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>( data, null ));
            case "and":
                #region and
                ExpressionAnalyzer.And and = (element as ExpressionAnalyzer.And);
                Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>> andResult1 = DivideRequest(and.tuple.Item1);
                Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>> andResult2 = DivideRequest(and.tuple.Item2);

                if (andResult1.Item1.Item2 != "")
                {
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.And andRetour1 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.And();
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.And andRetour2 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.And();

                    andRetour1.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(andResult1.Item2.Item1, and.tuple.Item2);
                    andRetour2.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(andResult1.Item2.Item2, and.tuple.Item2);

                    return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                          (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, andResult1.Item1.Item2), 
                           new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(andRetour1, andRetour2));
                }
                else if(andResult2.Item1.Item2 != "")
                {
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.And andRetour1 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.And();
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.And andRetour2 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.And();

                    andRetour1.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(and.tuple.Item1, andResult2.Item2.Item1);
                    andRetour2.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(and.tuple.Item1, andResult2.Item2.Item2);

                    return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                          (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, andResult2.Item1.Item2),
                           new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(andRetour1, andRetour2));
                }

                foreach (ExpressionAnalyzer.Data andData1 in andResult1.Item1.Item1)
                foreach (ExpressionAnalyzer.Data andData2 in andResult2.Item1.Item1)
                    if (andData1.type == "Price" && andData2.type == "Price" && andData1.currency == andData2.currency)
                    {
                        return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                              (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, "and"),
                               new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(and.tuple.Item1, and.tuple.Item2));
                    }

                List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data> andRetourDatas = andResult1.Item1.Item1;
                andRetourDatas.AddRange(andResult2.Item1.Item1);
                return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                            (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(andRetourDatas, ""),
                            new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(and, null));
                #endregion
            case "or":
                #region or
                ExpressionAnalyzer.Or or = (element as ExpressionAnalyzer.Or);
                Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>> orResult1 = DivideRequest(or.tuple.Item1);
                Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>> orResult2 = DivideRequest(or.tuple.Item2);

                if (orResult1.Item1.Item2 != "")
                {
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.Or orRetour1 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.Or();
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.Or orRetour2 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.Or();

                    orRetour1.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(orResult1.Item2.Item1, or.tuple.Item2);
                    orRetour2.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(orResult1.Item2.Item2, or.tuple.Item2);

                    return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                          (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, orResult1.Item1.Item2), 
                           new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(orRetour1, orRetour2));
                }
                else if(orResult2.Item1.Item2 != "")
                {
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.Or orRetour1 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.Or();
                    ExpressionAnalyzer.Or orRetour2 = new ExpressionAnalyzer.Or();

                    orRetour1.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(or.tuple.Item1, orResult2.Item2.Item1);
                    orRetour2.tuple = new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(or.tuple.Item1, orResult2.Item2.Item2);

                    return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                          (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, orResult2.Item1.Item2),
                           new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(orRetour1, orRetour2));
                }

                foreach (ExpressionAnalyzer.Data orData1 in orResult1.Item1.Item1)
                foreach (ExpressionAnalyzer.Data orData2 in orResult2.Item1.Item1)
                    if (orData1.type == "Data" && orData2.type == "Data")
                    {
                        return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                              (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(null, "or"),
                               new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(or.tuple.Item1, or.tuple.Item2));
                    }

                List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data> orRetourDatas = orResult1.Item1.Item1;
                orRetourDatas.AddRange(orResult2.Item1.Item1);
                return new Tuple<Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>, Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>>
                            (new Tuple<List<ExpressionAnalyzer.Data>, string>(orRetourDatas, ""),
                            new Tuple<ExpressionAnalyzer.Element, ExpressionAnalyzer.Element>(or, null));
                #endregion
        }
        return null;     
    }
```

An Element is the class herited by and, or and data. And and Or have a tuples: for their right and left side.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show?  These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Thank you Micky! I added the last version of the code I've been working on... and as I wrote, it's uterly messy. I'm pretty ashamed of it, thus why I didn't want to post it in the first place, haha!

Comment: it is still not clear to me what you are asking. you have a request and you want to transform it such that it meets the requirements? do we have  the guarantee that we could always transform the request?

Comment: Yes, there's that guarantee. In the very worst case, it would be possible to send each single leaves, one at a time. But then, there's that 'too many results' problem... but there's nothing the algorithme can really do about that.